# How to track a moving object by handler?

Tags: python

The cone can track the moving ball in view mode, but in rendering mode,it did not rotate and track anyway.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(radius1=0.4,radius2=1,depth=6,location=(0,0,0),rotation=(3.14/2,0,0))
mycone = bpy.context.object
mycone.name='mycone'
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=2,location=(0,0,4))
#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(location=(0,0,0))
mymonkey = bpy.context.object
mymonkey.name='mymonk'

degp = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
def my_handler(scene,degp):
    #scene = bpy.context.scene
    i_frame = scene.frame_current
    #print(i_frame)
    if not (0 <= i_frame < totalmoves):
        return
    newwing78=scene.objects.get('mymonk')
    newwing78_eval = newwing78.evaluated_get(degp)    
    me = newwing78_eval.data
    mat_world = newwing78.matrix_world
    p2n=newwing78_eval.location
    pos_world = mat_world @ p2n
    mycone=scene.objects.get("mycone")   
    mycone_eval = mycone.evaluated_get(degp)  
    cmw = mycone_eval.matrix_world
    
    direction = cmw.translation - mat_world @ pos_world
    M = direction.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y').to_matrix().to_4x4()
    M.translation = cmw.translation

    mycone.matrix_world = M
    #print(mat_world @ pos_world,direction[0],M,M.normalized(),M.to_3x3().normalized(),M[0][0])
    #is below useful?
    #mycone.rotation_euler=(M[0][0],M[1][1],M[2][2])
    degp.update()
    bpy.context.view_layer.update() 

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Comment: Please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote  .  Thankyou comments are appreciated, .....  to re-iterate   _"If this has helped, please consider accepting and / or upvoting."_

Comment: Does that mean that I vote your answers from other posts?

Comment: How can I vote your answer? Not showing !

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A99598+answers%3A1